# Trying to keep UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone while color needed in UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault in editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a subclassed UITableViewCell while setting:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

In:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In the table I've a multiple selection so I can delete rows from data source.

What I'm trying to get is these:

1. User tap on cell and there will not be a selection.
2. When user is in multiple selection(editing) mode, only the native multiple selection view will be `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault` while my designed cell won't get affected by the selection style.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most graceful way to do this would be to move the `selectionStyle` logic into your subclass.

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Set default selection style
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // Change the selection style based on if the cell is being edited or not
    if (editing) {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
    } else {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
}
```

While gabbler's method does work, you have to call `[_tableView reloadData];` which cancels the editing animation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when user is not in editing mode, tapping on cell results no selection. Here is the code to be added in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (tableView.editing) {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
} else {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

This will make selectionStyle in editing mode to be 
default style. Do remember to reload tableview when entering editing mode.

Comment: That's correct, but I still want when 'cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault' the selection frame will not include my custom cell.